# Unable to Set the LineStyle Property of the Border Class?

Tags: vba, excel

```
 With Sheets(1).Range(Cells(row + 1, 1), Cells(row + 1, "V"))
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 48
    ' .Borders (xlInsideHorizontal)
 .LineStyle = xlSlantDashDot
 .Weight = xlThin
 .ColorIndex = 15
 .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
 .Font.Size = 25
     End With
```

---

```
    .LineStyle = xlSlantDashDot
```

This is the line showing the error .

Is it about the MS office version ?

I m using MS officer 2010 version .

Or this property is too old ,that I can 't use `xlSlantDashDot` .

Any other excel cell thick linestyle suggested ?

---

The error is

> XL2002: Error Message: Run-Time Error 1004: Unable to Set the LineStyle Property of the Border Class

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/277577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to set the borders of your range, then You need to modify your line:

```
.LineStyle = xlSlantDashDot
```

to:

```
.Borders.LineStyle = xlSlantDashDot
```